# Arduino Serial.readStringUntil doesn't correctly detect terminator chars

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I have this code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial){}
  Serial.println("Connected");
  Serial.println("L");
  Serial.println("R");
  Serial.println("B");
  Serial.println("S");
  Serial.println("T");
}

void loop() {
  evalComms(Serial.readStringUntil("0"));
}

void evalComms(String recv){
  if (recv == "L"){
    Serial.println("ok L " + String(Serial.parseInt()));
  } else if (recv == "R"){
    Serial.println("ok R " + String(Serial.parseInt()));
  } else if (recv == "B") {
    Serial.println("ok B " + String(Serial.parseInt()));
  } else if (recv == "S") {
    Serial.println("ok S");
  } else if (recv == "T"){
    Serial.println("ok T");
  } else if (recv != ""){
     Serial.println("Comm error. Read: " + recv);
  }
}
```

Expected I/O scenario:
IN: L020
OUT: ok L 20

Actual I/O scenario:
IN: L020
OUT: Comm error. Read: L020

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`Serial.readStringUntil('0')` since as per [docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil) it accepts a `char`

Else I'd suggest to change the terminate character to say `\n` ( ENTER ) ,

then on serial : `"L\n20"` will give you correct output.

```
void loop() 
{
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        evalComms( Serial.readStringUntil('\n') );
    }
}
```